# Add trailing zeros to string

Tags: php

How can I add some trailing zeros to a string like in following example:

```
$number= sprintf("%04s", "02");
echo $number;
```

This displays 0002 but I want 0200

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know how long your original input will be and you want the padding to be flexible (I assume that is what you need...), you can set the padding to the other side like this:

```
$number= sprintf("%-04s", "02");
                   ^ here
echo $number;
```

Comment: Thank you. One last question. How I have to change the code If I have the number 1 and want the result 0100? (hex)

Comment: @Maddy I'm not sure what you are looking for, `"0100"` is just a string, if you want to convert it to another base as if it is a hex number, you can use for example `hexdec()`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
$number= str_pad("02", 4, 0);
echo $number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
str_pad('02', 4, '0');
```

Comment: this will result in "02" ... you have to set te length (second param) to 4 ;)

Comment: @tino.codes Good spot, corrected the example... long time since I used the function!