# Always get to x amount of numbers

Tags: php

I have a function that generates a random number, like:

```
$int = random_number();
```

Generally, the results are 6 digits, but occasionally, it ends up being less than 6 digits. How do I add zeros to the number if it is less than 6 digits? For example, if `$int` is `12345`, I turn it into `123450`.

I can easily do this with something like:

```
if (strlen($int) == 5) {
   $int = $int.'0';
} elseif(strlen($int) == 4){
   $int = $int.'00';
} //etc
```

But clearly there must be a better way?

Comment: Adding trailing zeroes to a number seems... wrong

Comment: @iainn I get your point but how can you say this without seeing the purpose of it.

Comment: Simple way `while(strlen($string) < 6) $string .= 0;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add trailing zeros to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479396/add-trailing-zeros-to-string/33479415)

Comment: `strlen($number)<6` is equivalent to `$number<100000`, and `$number.='0'` is equivalent to `$number*=10`. I mean, they are numbers, why treat them as strings? Also, if you want a number between 100000 and 999999, why not call `rand(100000,999999)` (see Vito Andolini's answer)?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Because treating numbers like strings is always going to have weird side-effects. Assuming a range of 0-999999, there are now six different ways of your function generating `100000`, which means it isn't distributed evenly. I don't know, maybe that's what you want, but it seems like a weird requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

strpadding this is called.

See here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Example:

```
echo str_pad($yourRandomNumber, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: Nice, this is the one!

Comment: Should be `STR_PAD_RIGHT` btw.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Yes, you want to add them at the end. My bad. But you figured it out. ;-)

Comment: It's not big deal in PHP, but after this method you will have *string* instead of *int*.

Answer (score 1):

Usually [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) works for this purpose, but **adds a leading zeros** what is not a OPs question.

```
$padded = sprintf('%06d', 123);
```

For **trailing zeros** with [`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) as brilliantly mentioned by *Ivar* (*in comments section below*) the following code will work:

```
$padded = sprintf('%-06s', 123);
```

## UPD

For adding **trailing zeros** [`str_pad`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) can be used.

```
$padded = str_pad($num, 6, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```

> Note: `STR_PAD_RIGHT` is a default argument, so can be omitted.

Comment: How does this turn it into 6 digits?

Comment: This adds leading zeroes. From the example in the question he wants trailing zeroes.

Comment: Also `STR_PAD_RIGHT` is the default so you can omit it.

Comment: @Ivar thanks a lot for mentioning both things! Trailing with `sprintf` is brilliant and I honestly completely forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use `rand(100000,999999);` if you're not using random number with extra parameters.

Answer (score -1):

```
$number = "878"; //the random number
$int = strlen($number);
$multiplier = 6 - $int;
if ($multiplier != 0) {
    $number = $number * pow(10 , $multiplier);
}
```

Its simple we just multiply with 10*10*10 (the number of missing numbers).

Comment: Its very simple what am i doing. Didn`t know i have to explain 3 lines of simple code. Its not as elegant as Erwin Moller asnwer but still does the job. What is the -1 for?

Comment: It's not my DV but probably the lack of explanation. Answers are suppose to have explanations.